# Network does not start on initial boot, but does on reboot

Tags: networking

Running Ubuntu 16.04.

Recently, my wired network connection does not start on an initial boot, but will start when I reboot.

Seems to be a problem related to eth0 vs. enp4s0 naming….

Started happening a week ago.

**From initial boot in syslog:**

```
Dec 14 09:35:06 Ubuntu16 dhclient[3110]: can't create /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases: Permission denied
Dec 14 09:35:06 Ubuntu16 : /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/avahi-autoipd returned non-zero exit status 1
Dec 14 09:35:06 Ubuntu16 dhclient[3110]: **Error getting hardware address for "eth0": No such device**
Dec 14 09:35:06 Ubuntu16 dhclient[3110]: 
Dec 14 09:35:06 Ubuntu16 dhclient[3110]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Dec 14 09:35:06 Ubuntu16 dhclient[3110]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Dec 14 09:35:06 Ubuntu16 dhclient[3110]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Dec 14 09:35:06 Ubuntu16 dhclient[3110]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Dec 14 09:35:06 Ubuntu16 dhclient[3110]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
Dec 14 09:35:06 Ubuntu16 dhclient[3110]: 
Dec 14 09:35:06 Ubuntu16 dhclient[3110]: exiting.
```

**From reboot in syslog:**

```
Dec 14 09:57:34 Ubuntu16 kernel: [    0.765525] alx 0000:04:00.0 eth0: Qualcomm Atheros AR816x/AR817x Ethernet [1c:1b:0d:32:c4:0b]
Dec 14 09:57:34 Ubuntu16 kernel: [    0.769209] ahci 0000:00:17.0: AHCI 0001.0301 32 slots 6 ports 6 Gbps 0x3f impl SATA mode
Dec 14 09:57:34 Ubuntu16 kernel: [    0.769212] ahci 0000:00:17.0: flags: 64bit ncq sntf pm led clo only pio slum part ems deso sadm sds apst 
Dec 14 09:57:34 Ubuntu16 kernel: [    0.791858] alx 0000:04:00.0 **enp4s0: renamed from eth0**
```

Comment: Run this [script](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205) and post it [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, since nobody else had any ideas....

The motherboard is Gigabyte H170-Gaming 3.  An upgrade of the BIOS appears to have solved the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem. I found this post by googling the error code (-110). Coincidentally I have the same motherboard. Sounds like a hardware/BIOS defect.

Answer (score 0):

Some additional info from syslog:

**Initial power on and boot - no network**

Dec 19 08:05:39 kernel: [    0.766660] alx 0000:04:00.0: MAC Reset failed, error = -110

Dec 19 08:05:39 kernel: [    0.766717] alx: probe of 0000:04:00.0 failed with error -110

**The reboot - network is enabled OK**

Dec 19 08:06:17 kernel: [    0.761250] alx 0000:04:00.0 eth0: Qualcomm Atheros AR816x/AR817x Ethernet [1c:1b:0d:32:c4:0b]

Dec 19 08:06:17 kernel: [    0.788661] alx 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: renamed from eth0

Comment: No ideas from anyone?  This still happens intermittently. Occasionally Ubuntu boots with the network down.  A reboot fixes it 100% of the time.  25% of the time, initial boot does not bring up the network connection.